# Chromecast HLS media stalled after short delay

Tags: chromecast, google-cast, http-live-streaming

The HLS media that I'm attempting to stream on my Chromecast is stalling after approximately 5 seconds. I have ensured that CORS header is present in the stream. I'm using the sample custom receiver from GitHub (https://github.com/googlecast/cast-custom-receiver/blob/master/sample_media_receiver.html).

The stream is:

http://ckpk.streamon.fm/hlsts/CKPK-48k.m3u8

The last time I tested this stream (approximately August 20th, 2014), it was streaming just fine but a few days ago I tried it and this stalling issue started occurring. Can someone please let me know if the stream is invalid now?

EDIT: Enabled Media Player debug logging. Updating console output.

Console output:

```
### Application Loaded. Starting system. receiver.php?stationId=4:115
 [  0.536s] [cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager] Version: 2.0.0.0011 cast_receiver.js:18
 [  0.556s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Using default Player cast_receiver.js:18
 [  0.574s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] Opening message bus websocket cast_receiver.js:18
 [  0.579s] [goog.net.WebSocket] Opening the WebSocket on ws://localhost:8008/v2/ipc cast_receiver.js:18
 [  0.676s] [goog.net.WebSocket] WebSocket opened on ws://localhost:8008/v2/ipc cast_receiver.js:18
 [  0.685s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IpcChannel opened cast_receiver.js:18
 [  0.689s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message cast_receiver.js:18
 [  0.696s] [cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager] Underlying message bus is open cast_receiver.js:18
 [  0.701s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IPC message sent: {"namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.system","senderId":"SystemSender","data":"{\"type\":\"ready\",\"statusText\":\"Ready to play\",\"activeNamespaces\":[\"urn:x-cast:com.google.devrel.custom\",\"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media\"],\"version\":\"2.0.0\",\"messagesVersion\":\"1.0\"}"} cast_receiver.js:18
 [  0.705s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IPC message sent: {"namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.system","senderId":"SystemSender","data":"{\"type\":\"startheartbeat\",\"maxInactivity\":6000}"} cast_receiver.js:18
 [  0.722s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] Received message: {"data":"{\"applicationId\":\"CDA37AD1\",\"applicationName\":\"APP_NAME\",\"launchingSenderId\":\"66:<packageId>-103\",\"messagesVersion\":\"1.0\",\"sessionId\":\"0CEBF071-D6E9-4BD2-5AA8-894719FF04A7\",\"type\":\"ready\",\"version\":\"1.0\"}","namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.system","senderId":"SystemSender"} cast_receiver.js:18
 [  0.729s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message cast_receiver.js:18
 [  0.732s] [cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager] Dispatching CastReceiverManager system ready event cast_receiver.js:18
### Cast Receiver Manager is READY: {"type":"ready","I":false,"defaultPrevented":false,"lb":true,"data":{"id":"CDA37AD1","name":"APP_NAME","sessionId":"0CEBF071-D6E9-4BD2-5AA8-894719FF04A7","namespaces":["urn:x-cast:com.google.devrel.custom","urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media"],"launchingSenderId":"66:<packageId>-103"}} receiver.php?stationId=4:149
 [  0.900s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] Received message: {"data":"{\"senderId\":\"66:<packageId>-103\",\"type\":\"senderconnected\",\"userAgent\":\"Android CastSDK,6109000,Nexus 5,hammerhead,4.4.4\"}","namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.system","senderId":"SystemSender"} cast_receiver.js:18
 [  0.902s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message cast_receiver.js:18
 [  0.909s] [cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager] Dispatching CastReceiverManager sender connected event [66:<packageId>-103] cast_receiver.js:18
 [  0.917s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Registering sender [urn:x-cast:com.google.devrel.custom, 66:<packageId>-103] cast_receiver.js:18
 [  0.918s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Registering sender [urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media, 66:<packageId>-103] cast_receiver.js:18
### Cast Receiver Manager - Sender Connected : {"type":"senderconnected","I":false,"defaultPrevented":false,"lb":true,"data":"66:<packageId>-103","senderId":"66:<packageId>-103","userAgent":"Android CastSDK,6109000,Nexus 5,hammerhead,4.4.4"} receiver.php?stationId=4:162
 [  0.931s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] Received message: {"data":"{\"type\":\"GET_STATUS\",\"requestId\":1}","namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media","senderId":"66:<packageId>-103"} cast_receiver.js:18
 [  0.935s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message cast_receiver.js:18
 [  0.938s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] MediaManager message received cast_receiver.js:18
 [  0.939s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Dispatching MediaManager getStatus event cast_receiver.js:18
### Media Manager - GET STATUS: {"type":"getstatus","I":false,"defaultPrevented":false,"lb":true,"data":{"requestId":1},"senderId":"66:<packageId>-103"} receiver.php?stationId=4:310
 [  0.944s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] onGetStatus cast_receiver.js:18
 [  0.947s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Sending status message to 66:<packageId>-103 cast_receiver.js:18
 [  0.950s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IPC message sent: {"namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media","senderId":"66:<packageId>-103","data":"{\"type\":\"MEDIA_STATUS\",\"status\":[],\"requestId\":1}"} cast_receiver.js:18
 [  0.955s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] getCurrentTimeSec: 0 cast_receiver.js:18
 [  0.958s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] Received message: {"data":"{\"currentTime\":0,\"type\":\"LOAD\",\"media\":{\"streamType\":\"LIVE\",\"duration\":0,\"contentType\":\"application\\/x-mpegURL\",\"contentId\":\"http:\\/\\/ckkq.streamon.fm\\/hlsts\\/CKKQ-48k.m3u8\",\"metadata\":{\"title\":\"100.3 APP_NAME! The Island's Rock\",\"metadataType\":1}},\"requestId\":2,\"autoplay\":true}","namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media","senderId":"66:<packageId>-103"} cast_receiver.js:18
 [  0.960s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message cast_receiver.js:18
 [  0.962s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] MediaManager message received cast_receiver.js:18
 [  0.964s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Dispatching MediaManager load event cast_receiver.js:18
### Media Manager - LOAD: {"type":"load","I":false,"defaultPrevented":false,"lb":true,"data":{"currentTime":0,"media":{"streamType":"LIVE","duration":0,"contentType":"application/x-mpegURL","contentId":"http://ckkq.streamon.fm/hlsts/CKKQ-48k.m3u8","metadata":{"title":"100.3 APP_NAME! The Island's Rock","metadataType":1}},"requestId":2,"autoplay":true},"senderId":"66:<packageId>-103"} receiver.php?stationId=4:478
### Media Protocol Identified as m3u8 receiver.php?stationId=4:521
 [  0.847s] [cast.player.api.Player] Version: 0.7.0.5
 media_player.js:24
 [  0.857s] [cast.player.api.Player] load 
 media_player.js:24
######### MEDIA ELEMENT LOAD START receiver.php?stationId=4:585
 [  0.891s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Opening Xhr [GET http://ckkq.streamon.fm/hlsts/CKKQ-48k.m3u8 -1]
 media_player.js:24
 [  0.905s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Will abort after 30000ms if incomplete, xhr2 false [GET http://ckkq.streamon.fm/hlsts/CKKQ-48k.m3u8 -1]
 media_player.js:24
 [  0.909s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Sending request [GET http://ckkq.streamon.fm/hlsts/CKKQ-48k.m3u8 -1]
 media_player.js:24
 [  1.432s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Request complete [GET http://ckkq.streamon.fm/hlsts/CKKQ-48k.m3u8 200]
 media_player.js:24
 [  1.475s] [cast.player.core.QualityManager] 0: from undefined to 48000
 media_player.js:24
 [  1.479s] [cast.player.hls.Playlist] update: http://ckkq.streamon.fm/hlsts/stream/CKKQ-48k.aac.m3u8?uid=ijen9h9n5u&starttime=1412277294
 media_player.js:24
 [  1.483s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Opening Xhr [GET http://ckkq.streamon.fm/hlsts/stream/CKKQ-48k.aac.m3u8?uid=ijen9h9n5u&starttime=1412277294 -1]
 media_player.js:24
 [  1.491s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Will abort after 30000ms if incomplete, xhr2 false [GET http://ckkq.streamon.fm/hlsts/stream/CKKQ-48k.aac.m3u8?uid=ijen9h9n5u&starttime=1412277294 -1]
 media_player.js:24
 [  1.494s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Sending request [GET http://ckkq.streamon.fm/hlsts/stream/CKKQ-48k.aac.m3u8?uid=ijen9h9n5u&starttime=1412277294 -1]
 media_player.js:24
 [  1.598s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Request complete [GET http://ckkq.streamon.fm/hlsts/stream/CKKQ-48k.aac.m3u8?uid=ijen9h9n5u&starttime=1412277294 200]
 media_player.js:24
 [  1.639s] [cast.player.hls.Playlist] update in: 5000
 media_player.js:24
 [  1.653s] [cast.player.core.SegmentManager] 0: seek success 0
 media_player.js:24
 [  1.660s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Opening Xhr [GET http://ckkq.streamon.fm/hlsts/stream/0323de177b6e1df66d27dfe9f4ea85db2ef12762.ts -1]
 media_player.js:24
 [  1.664s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Will abort after 15000ms if incomplete, xhr2 false [GET http://ckkq.streamon.fm/hlsts/stream/0323de177b6e1df66d27dfe9f4ea85db2ef12762.ts -1]
 media_player.js:24
 [  1.667s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Sending request [GET http://ckkq.streamon.fm/hlsts/stream/0323de177b6e1df66d27dfe9f4ea85db2ef12762.ts -1]
 media_player.js:24
 [  3.244s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Request complete [GET http://ckkq.streamon.fm/hlsts/stream/0323de177b6e1df66d27dfe9f4ea85db2ef12762.ts 200]
 media_player.js:24
 [  3.248s] [cast.player.core.QualityManager] 0: current=166375.86, average=745608.70
 media_player.js:24
 [  3.267s] [cast.player.hls.Protocol] start: 1.4
 media_player.js:24
 [  3.276s] [cast.player.core.SourceBufferManager] 0: abort
 media_player.js:24
 [  3.279s] [cast.player.core.SourceBufferManager] 0: timestampOffset = -1.4
 media_player.js:24
 [  3.281s] [cast.player.core.SourceBufferManager] 0: append
 media_player.js:24
 [  3.309s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Opening Xhr [GET http://ckkq.streamon.fm/hlsts/stream/68cd7a04e2c9970e3597f11c2d5eaafc8c0cf067.ts -1]
 media_player.js:24
 [  3.313s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Will abort after 15000ms if incomplete, xhr2 false [GET http://ckkq.streamon.fm/hlsts/stream/68cd7a04e2c9970e3597f11c2d5eaafc8c0cf067.ts -1]
 media_player.js:24
 [  3.315s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Sending request [GET http://ckkq.streamon.fm/hlsts/stream/68cd7a04e2c9970e3597f11c2d5eaafc8c0cf067.ts -1]
 media_player.js:24
 [  3.322s] [cast.player.core.SourceBufferManager] 0: 0 - 4.969069957733154
 media_player.js:24
 [  3.324s] [cast.player.core.SourceBufferManager] 0: updateend
 media_player.js:24
 [  3.504s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] onMetadataLoadedInternal_: 0 0 cast_receiver.js:18
 [  3.508s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Metadata loaded cast_receiver.js:18
 [  3.520s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Sending broadcast status message cast_receiver.js:18
 [  3.536s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] getCurrentTimeSec: 0 cast_receiver.js:18
 [  3.548s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IPC message sent: {"namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media","senderId":"*:*","data":"{\"type\":\"MEDIA_STATUS\",\"status\":[{\"mediaSessionId\":1,\"playbackRate\":1,\"playerState\":\"BUFFERING\",\"currentTime\":0,\"supportedMediaCommands\":15,\"volume\":{\"level\":1,\"muted\":false},\"media\":{\"streamType\":\"LIVE\",\"duration\":null,\"contentType\":\"application/x-mpegURL\",\"contentId\":\"http://ckkq.streamon.fm/hlsts/CKKQ-48k.m3u8\",\"metadata\":{\"title\":\"100.3 APP_NAME! The Island's Rock\",\"metadataType\":1}}}],\"requestId\":2}"} cast_receiver.js:18
 [  3.559s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] getCurrentTimeSec: 0 cast_receiver.js:18
 [  3.418s] [cast.player.api.Player] loadedmetadata
 media_player.js:24
######### MEDIA ELEMENT SEEKING [object Event] receiver.php?stationId=4:629
 [  3.455s] [cast.player.api.Player] seeking
 media_player.js:24
 [  3.481s] [cast.player.core.SegmentManager] 0: reset
 media_player.js:24
 [  3.499s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Aborting [GET http://ckkq.streamon.fm/hlsts/stream/68cd7a04e2c9970e3597f11c2d5eaafc8c0cf067.ts -1]
 media_player.js:24
 [  3.533s] [cast.player.core.SourceBufferManager] 0: abort
 media_player.js:24
 [  3.540s] [cast.player.core.SourceBufferManager] 0: remove
 media_player.js:24
######### MEDIA ELEMENT SEEKED [object Event] receiver.php?stationId=4:633
######### MEDIA ELEMENT DATA LOADED receiver.php?stationId=4:589
######### MEDIA ELEMENT CAN PLAY receiver.php?stationId=4:593
 [  3.567s] [cast.player.api.Player] play
 media_player.js:24
######### MEDIA ELEMENT PLAYING receiver.php?stationId=4:601
 [  3.740s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] getCurrentTimeSec: 0 cast_receiver.js:18
 [  3.703s] [cast.player.core.SegmentManager] 0: seek success 0
 media_player.js:24
 [  3.705s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Opening Xhr [GET http://ckkq.streamon.fm/hlsts/stream/0323de177b6e1df66d27dfe9f4ea85db2ef12762.ts -1]
 media_player.js:24
 [  3.713s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Will abort after 15000ms if incomplete, xhr2 false [GET http://ckkq.streamon.fm/hlsts/stream/0323de177b6e1df66d27dfe9f4ea85db2ef12762.ts -1]
 media_player.js:24
 [  3.714s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Sending request [GET http://ckkq.streamon.fm/hlsts/stream/0323de177b6e1df66d27dfe9f4ea85db2ef12762.ts -1]
 media_player.js:24
 [  3.724s] [cast.player.api.Player] auto pause 0
 media_player.js:24
 [  3.735s] [cast.player.core.SourceBufferManager] 0: updateend
 media_player.js:24
 [  5.958s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Request complete [GET http://ckkq.streamon.fm/hlsts/stream/0323de177b6e1df66d27dfe9f4ea85db2ef12762.ts 200]
 media_player.js:24
 [  5.961s] [cast.player.core.QualityManager] 0: current=117385.37, average=305852.37
 media_player.js:24
 [  5.973s] [cast.player.core.SourceBufferManager] 0: append
 media_player.js:24
 [  5.985s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Opening Xhr [GET http://ckkq.streamon.fm/hlsts/stream/68cd7a04e2c9970e3597f11c2d5eaafc8c0cf067.ts -1]
 media_player.js:24
 [  5.987s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Will abort after 15000ms if incomplete, xhr2 false [GET http://ckkq.streamon.fm/hlsts/stream/68cd7a04e2c9970e3597f11c2d5eaafc8c0cf067.ts -1]
 media_player.js:24
 [  5.988s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Sending request [GET http://ckkq.streamon.fm/hlsts/stream/68cd7a04e2c9970e3597f11c2d5eaafc8c0cf067.ts -1]
 media_player.js:24
 [  5.995s] [cast.player.core.SourceBufferManager] 0: 9.938143730163574 - 14.907214164733887
 media_player.js:24
 [  5.997s] [cast.player.core.SourceBufferManager] 0: updateend
 media_player.js:24
 [  6.656s] [cast.player.hls.Playlist] update: http://ckkq.streamon.fm/hlsts/stream/CKKQ-48k.aac.m3u8?uid=ijen9h9n5u&starttime=1412277294
 media_player.js:24
 [  6.661s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Opening Xhr [GET http://ckkq.streamon.fm/hlsts/stream/CKKQ-48k.aac.m3u8?uid=ijen9h9n5u&starttime=1412277294 -1]
 media_player.js:24
 [  6.663s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Will abort after 30000ms if incomplete, xhr2 false [GET http://ckkq.streamon.fm/hlsts/stream/CKKQ-48k.aac.m3u8?uid=ijen9h9n5u&starttime=1412277294 -1]
 media_player.js:24
 [  6.665s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Sending request [GET http://ckkq.streamon.fm/hlsts/stream/CKKQ-48k.aac.m3u8?uid=ijen9h9n5u&starttime=1412277294 -1]
 media_player.js:24
 [  6.900s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Request complete [GET http://ckkq.streamon.fm/hlsts/stream/CKKQ-48k.aac.m3u8?uid=ijen9h9n5u&starttime=1412277294 200]
 media_player.js:24
 [  6.911s] [cast.player.hls.Playlist] update in: 5000
 media_player.js:24
 [  7.398s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Request complete [GET http://ckkq.streamon.fm/hlsts/stream/68cd7a04e2c9970e3597f11c2d5eaafc8c0cf067.ts 200]
 media_player.js:24
 [  7.400s] [cast.player.core.QualityManager] 0: current=185875.71, average=221868.70
 media_player.js:24
 [  7.404s] [cast.player.core.SourceBufferManager] 0: append
 media_player.js:24
 [  7.410s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Opening Xhr [GET http://ckkq.streamon.fm/hlsts/stream/93e1aa0e4d9e1cacddbec3814eb4c0edb65f3c88.ts -1]
 media_player.js:24
 [  7.412s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Will abort after 15000ms if incomplete, xhr2 false [GET http://ckkq.streamon.fm/hlsts/stream/93e1aa0e4d9e1cacddbec3814eb4c0edb65f3c88.ts -1]
 media_player.js:24
 [  7.414s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Sending request [GET http://ckkq.streamon.fm/hlsts/stream/93e1aa0e4d9e1cacddbec3814eb4c0edb65f3c88.ts -1]
 media_player.js:24
 [  7.421s] [cast.player.core.SourceBufferManager] 0: 9.938143730163574 - 19.87628173828125
 media_player.js:24
 [  7.423s] [cast.player.core.SourceBufferManager] 0: updateend
 media_player.js:24
 [  8.505s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Request complete [GET http://ckkq.streamon.fm/hlsts/stream/93e1aa0e4d9e1cacddbec3814eb4c0edb65f3c88.ts 200]
 media_player.js:24
 [  8.507s] [cast.player.core.QualityManager] 0: current=239927.07, average=234509.56
 media_player.js:24
 [  8.510s] [cast.player.core.SourceBufferManager] 0: append
 media_player.js:24
 [  8.516s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Opening Xhr [GET http://ckkq.streamon.fm/hlsts/stream/019055911a5ba83d0ff0771e5c2523df42955318.ts -1]
 media_player.js:24
 [  8.519s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Will abort after 15000ms if incomplete, xhr2 false [GET http://ckkq.streamon.fm/hlsts/stream/019055911a5ba83d0ff0771e5c2523df42955318.ts -1]
 media_player.js:24
 [  8.520s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Sending request [GET http://ckkq.streamon.fm/hlsts/stream/019055911a5ba83d0ff0771e5c2523df42955318.ts -1]
 media_player.js:24
 [  8.525s] [cast.player.api.Player] auto resume 0.232177
 media_player.js:24
 [  8.532s] [cast.player.core.SourceBufferManager] 0: 9.938143730163574 - 24.845354080200195
 media_player.js:24
 [  8.533s] [cast.player.core.SourceBufferManager] 0: updateend
 media_player.js:24
 [  8.548s] [cast.player.api.Player] play
 media_player.js:24
######### MEDIA ELEMENT PLAYING receiver.php?stationId=4:601
 [  8.786s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] getCurrentTimeSec: 0.754622 cast_receiver.js:18
 [  8.789s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Buffering state changed, isPlayerBuffering: false old time: 0 current time: 0.754622 cast_receiver.js:18
 [  8.790s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Sending broadcast status message cast_receiver.js:18
 [  8.792s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] getCurrentTimeSec: 0.754622 cast_receiver.js:18
 [  8.796s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IPC message sent: {"namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media","senderId":"*:*","data":"{\"type\":\"MEDIA_STATUS\",\"status\":[{\"mediaSessionId\":1,\"playbackRate\":1,\"playerState\":\"PLAYING\",\"currentTime\":0.754622,\"supportedMediaCommands\":15,\"volume\":{\"level\":1,\"muted\":false}}],\"requestId\":0}"} cast_receiver.js:18
 [  8.800s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] getCurrentTimeSec: 0.754622 cast_receiver.js:18
 [  9.795s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] getCurrentTimeSec: 1.799533 cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 10.461s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Request complete [GET http://ckkq.streamon.fm/hlsts/stream/019055911a5ba83d0ff0771e5c2523df42955318.ts 200]
 media_player.js:24
 [ 10.463s] [cast.player.core.QualityManager] 0: current=136727.27, average=166061.96
 media_player.js:24
 [ 10.468s] [cast.player.core.SourceBufferManager] 0: append
 media_player.js:24
 [ 10.475s] [cast.player.core.SourceBufferManager] 0: 9.938143730163574 - 29.814416885375977
 media_player.js:24
 [ 10.477s] [cast.player.core.SourceBufferManager] 0: updateend
 media_player.js:24
 [ 10.805s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] getCurrentTimeSec: 2.835711 cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 11.815s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] getCurrentTimeSec: 3.6194 cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 11.926s] [cast.player.hls.Playlist] update: http://ckkq.streamon.fm/hlsts/stream/CKKQ-48k.aac.m3u8?uid=ijen9h9n5u&starttime=1412277294
 media_player.js:24
 [ 11.927s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Opening Xhr [GET http://ckkq.streamon.fm/hlsts/stream/CKKQ-48k.aac.m3u8?uid=ijen9h9n5u&starttime=1412277294 -1]
 media_player.js:24
 [ 11.929s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Will abort after 30000ms if incomplete, xhr2 false [GET http://ckkq.streamon.fm/hlsts/stream/CKKQ-48k.aac.m3u8?uid=ijen9h9n5u&starttime=1412277294 -1]
 media_player.js:24
 [ 11.931s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Sending request [GET http://ckkq.streamon.fm/hlsts/stream/CKKQ-48k.aac.m3u8?uid=ijen9h9n5u&starttime=1412277294 -1]
 media_player.js:24
 [ 12.473s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Request complete [GET http://ckkq.streamon.fm/hlsts/stream/CKKQ-48k.aac.m3u8?uid=ijen9h9n5u&starttime=1412277294 200]
 media_player.js:24
 [ 12.482s] [cast.player.hls.Playlist] update in: 5000
 media_player.js:24
 [ 12.566s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Opening Xhr [GET http://ckkq.streamon.fm/hlsts/stream/3dfc5bb568a94d2fe0a110c025828e8813a20175.ts -1]
 media_player.js:24
 [ 12.568s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Will abort after 15000ms if incomplete, xhr2 false [GET http://ckkq.streamon.fm/hlsts/stream/3dfc5bb568a94d2fe0a110c025828e8813a20175.ts -1]
 media_player.js:24
 [ 12.570s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Sending request [GET http://ckkq.streamon.fm/hlsts/stream/3dfc5bb568a94d2fe0a110c025828e8813a20175.ts -1]
 media_player.js:24
 [ 12.825s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] getCurrentTimeSec: 4.655577 cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 13.371s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Request complete [GET http://ckkq.streamon.fm/hlsts/stream/3dfc5bb568a94d2fe0a110c025828e8813a20175.ts 200]
 media_player.js:24
 [ 13.375s] [cast.player.core.QualityManager] 0: current=329873.61, average=280730.11
 media_player.js:24
 [ 13.378s] [cast.player.core.SourceBufferManager] 0: append
 media_player.js:24
 [ 13.383s] [cast.player.core.SourceBufferManager] 0: 9.938143730163574 - 34.78349304199219
 media_player.js:24
 [ 13.385s] [cast.player.core.SourceBufferManager] 0: updateend
 media_player.js:24
 [ 13.835s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] getCurrentTimeSec: 4.969044 cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 14.845s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] getCurrentTimeSec: 4.969044 cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 14.847s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Buffering state changed, isPlayerBuffering: true old time: 4.969044 current time: 4.969044 cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 14.849s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Sending broadcast status message cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 14.850s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] getCurrentTimeSec: 4.969044 cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 14.852s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IPC message sent: {"namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media","senderId":"*:*","data":"{\"type\":\"MEDIA_STATUS\",\"status\":[{\"mediaSessionId\":1,\"playbackRate\":1,\"playerState\":\"BUFFERING\",\"currentTime\":4.969044,\"supportedMediaCommands\":15,\"volume\":{\"level\":1,\"muted\":false}}],\"requestId\":0}"} cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 14.856s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] getCurrentTimeSec: 4.969044 cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 15.845s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] getCurrentTimeSec: 4.969044 cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 16.855s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] getCurrentTimeSec: 4.969044 cast_receiver.js:18
######### MEDIA ELEMENT STALLED receiver.php?stationId=4:609
 [ 17.496s] [cast.player.hls.Playlist] update: http://ckkq.streamon.fm/hlsts/stream/CKKQ-48k.aac.m3u8?uid=ijen9h9n5u&starttime=1412277294
 media_player.js:24
 [ 17.498s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Opening Xhr [GET http://ckkq.streamon.fm/hlsts/stream/CKKQ-48k.aac.m3u8?uid=ijen9h9n5u&starttime=1412277294 -1]
 media_player.js:24
 [ 17.499s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Will abort after 30000ms if incomplete, xhr2 false [GET http://ckkq.streamon.fm/hlsts/stream/CKKQ-48k.aac.m3u8?uid=ijen9h9n5u&starttime=1412277294 -1]
 media_player.js:24
 [ 17.501s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Sending request [GET http://ckkq.streamon.fm/hlsts/stream/CKKQ-48k.aac.m3u8?uid=ijen9h9n5u&starttime=1412277294 -1]
 media_player.js:24
 [ 17.631s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Request complete [GET http://ckkq.streamon.fm/hlsts/stream/CKKQ-48k.aac.m3u8?uid=ijen9h9n5u&starttime=1412277294 200]
 media_player.js:24
 [ 17.636s] [cast.player.hls.Playlist] update in: 5000
 media_player.js:24
 [ 17.865s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] getCurrentTimeSec: 4.969044 cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 18.875s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] getCurrentTimeSec: 4.969044 cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 19.885s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] getCurrentTimeSec: 4.969044 cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 20.885s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] getCurrentTimeSec: 4.969044 cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 21.895s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] getCurrentTimeSec: 4.969044 cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 22.646s] [cast.player.hls.Playlist] update: http://ckkq.streamon.fm/hlsts/stream/CKKQ-48k.aac.m3u8?uid=ijen9h9n5u&starttime=1412277294
 media_player.js:24
 [ 22.647s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Opening Xhr [GET http://ckkq.streamon.fm/hlsts/stream/CKKQ-48k.aac.m3u8?uid=ijen9h9n5u&starttime=1412277294 -1]
 media_player.js:24
 [ 22.650s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Will abort after 30000ms if incomplete, xhr2 false [GET http://ckkq.streamon.fm/hlsts/stream/CKKQ-48k.aac.m3u8?uid=ijen9h9n5u&starttime=1412277294 -1]
 media_player.js:24
 [ 22.651s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Sending request [GET http://ckkq.streamon.fm/hlsts/stream/CKKQ-48k.aac.m3u8?uid=ijen9h9n5u&starttime=1412277294 -1]
 media_player.js:24
 [ 22.905s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] getCurrentTimeSec: 4.969044 cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 23.915s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] getCurrentTimeSec: 4.969044 cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 24.925s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] getCurrentTimeSec: 4.969044 cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 25.927s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] getCurrentTimeSec: 4.969044 cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 26.935s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] getCurrentTimeSec: 4.969044 cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 27.945s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] getCurrentTimeSec: 4.969044 cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 28.955s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] getCurrentTimeSec: 4.969044 cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 29.965s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] getCurrentTimeSec: 4.969044 cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 30.976s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] getCurrentTimeSec: 4.969044 cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 31.985s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] getCurrentTimeSec: 4.969044 cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 32.996s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] getCurrentTimeSec: 4.969044 cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 34.005s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] getCurrentTimeSec: 4.969044 cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 35.015s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] getCurrentTimeSec: 4.969044 cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 36.026s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] getCurrentTimeSec: 4.969044 cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 37.035s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] getCurrentTimeSec: 4.969044 cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 38.045s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] getCurrentTimeSec: 4.969044 cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 39.055s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] getCurrentTimeSec: 4.969044 cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 40.066s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] getCurrentTimeSec: 4.969044 cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 41.076s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] getCurrentTimeSec: 4.969044 cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 42.086s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] getCurrentTimeSec: 4.969044 cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 43.095s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] getCurrentTimeSec: 4.969044 cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 44.105s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] getCurrentTimeSec: 4.969044 cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 45.115s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] getCurrentTimeSec: 4.969044 cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 46.126s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] getCurrentTimeSec: 4.969044 cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 47.135s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] getCurrentTimeSec: 4.969044 cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 48.145s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] getCurrentTimeSec: 4.969044 cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 49.155s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] getCurrentTimeSec: 4.969044 cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 50.165s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] getCurrentTimeSec: 4.969044 cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 51.175s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] getCurrentTimeSec: 4.969044 cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 52.185s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] getCurrentTimeSec: 4.969044 cast_receiver.js:18
```

Comment: I suggest you use the Default or Styled receiver for testing this stream; the project you are using is pointing to a unsupported old version of the MPL library.

Comment: @AliNaddaf I was under the impression that the default/styled receiver doesn't support HLS media. Does it utilize the MPL?

Comment: I don't know where you heard that but the Default and Styled receivers have full support for HLS and other adaptive bit rate streams.

Comment: @AliNaddaf I also logged an issue with the Google Cast SDK Issue Tracker ([Issue 404](https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=404)). Can you please let me know if the updated console log I posted sheds new light on the issue. Thank you.